# how to write a method that translates a boolean into "yes" or "no"

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I"m need to write a method that translates a boolean true or false into a string "yes" or "no". I'm kinda lost.

```
public class Book
{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;
    private int pages;
    private boolean pback;
    private double price;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Book
     */
    public Book(String bookTitle, String bookAuthor, String bookCode, int bookPages, boolean paperback, double bookRetail)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        title = bookTitle;
        author = bookAuthor;
        isbn = bookCode;
        pages = bookPages;
        pback = paperback;
        price = bookRetail;
    }


public String translate(boolean trueorFalse)
            {
                if(pback = true)
                    {
                        ??????;
                    }            
                 else(pback = false)
                    {
                        ???????;
                    } 

            }
```

Comment: The code in your translate() function is incorrect.  You are using an assignment operator in the if statement and else clause instead of the equality operator.  You also don't have a closing brace for the class definition.  Small things, and I'm sure nobody will try to get this code running, but it's nice to have things correct :)

Comment: Developers who write b == true or b == false should be sent off to boolean boot camp for reeducation.

Answer (score 36):

```
boolean myBoolean = true;
String result = myBoolean ? "yes" : "no";
```

Comment: Doesn't this particular example always return "yes"? :) Or am I not getting the joke?

Comment: It's an example. myBoolean is assumed to be some as of yet undetermined boolean value, not explicitly defined as true in all cases.

Answer (score 27):

The [conditional operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25) is your friend:

```
public static String translate(boolean trueOrFalse) {
    return trueOrFalse ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

In general, if you find yourself writing:

```
SomeType x;
if (someCondition) {
    x = someExpression;
} else {
    x = someOtherExpression;
}
```

it's generally nicer to use:

```
SomeType x = someCondition ? someExpression : someOtherExpression;
```

The conditional operator makes sure that only one of `someExpression` or `someOtherExpression` is evaluated, so you can use method calls etc, confident that they won't be executed inappropriately.

Of course there are times when this gets too complicated - you need to judge the readability of each form for yourself.

Comment: "The conditional operator makes sure that only one of someExpression or someOtherExpression is evaluated, so you can use method calls etc, confident that they won't be executed inappropriately." the same is true of using the if-else construct

Comment: @matt b - exactly, which is why they're interchangeable. The point is that it's *not* the same as IIF in VB, for example - one common concern is that *both* of the second and third expressions might get evaluated, which isn't actually a problem.

Answer (score 9):

There is a project from Apache Group called [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) for working with common Java classes like `Boolean`. Its [`BooleanUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html) class has some nice methods to work with:

```
toStringOnOff(boolean bool) - converts a boolean to a String returning 'on' or 'off'
toStringOnOff(Boolean bool) - converts a Boolean to a String returning 'on', 'off' or null
toStringTrueFalse(boolean bool) - converts a boolean to a String returning 'true' or 'false'
toStringTrueFalse(Boolean bool) - converts a Boolean to a String returning 'true', 'false' or null
toStringYesNo(boolean bool) - converts a boolean to a String returning 'yes' or 'no'
toStringYesNo(Boolean bool) - converts a Boolean to a String returning 'yes', 'no' or null
```

In your example you should work with the [`toStringYesNo`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toStringYesNo-boolean-) method.

```java
boolean myBoolean = false;
String result = BooleanUtils.toStringYesNo(myBoolean);
System.out.println(result);
```

This will print

```
no
```

To add the library to your project just add it to your [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) `pom.xml` dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(pback == true)
{
    return "yes";
} else {
    return "no";
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- equality is tested using `==`, so you should write `if ( a == b )` , not `if ( a = b )`;
- returning a value from  a method is done using the keyword `return` followed by the value;
- else does not take a supplementary argument, unless you want to say `else if` which then takes an expression similar to `if`, e.g. `else if ( a ==b )`.

Comment: Testing against true/false is kinda redundant compared with `if (pback)` or (for the reverse) `if (!pback)`. I very rarely compare against true/false. Likewise I'd always use the conditional operator for this situation.

Comment: @Jon : I agree. My aim was to give the simplest possible solution, as the asker indicated he is just starting with Java.

Comment: I'd say the conditional operator *is* the simplest possible solution - but even if I were presenting the if/else version, I'd at least have mentioned that you didn't need the "==" at all.

Comment: @starblue The answer indicates what I believe is best for the asker. The last think I want is to generate more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (pback) {
    return "yes";
}
else {
    return "no";
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Technically speaking, you're missing a '}' :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, the parameter for your translate method is never used. You should fix that.

Second, do you need to use the String values "Yes" and "No" for conditionals? If not and you can just use the boolean version(and I see no reason that you couldn't) I suggest leaving the boolean.

You can then translate that boolean into "Yes" or "No" when it is outputted using something like the following code:

```
        //say your boolean variable is called gotIt
            if(gotIt == true) //you can also just say if(gotIt) here
                {
                    //here you place the string where it needs to be, either output it or place it into a variable
                     System.out.println("Yes");
                }            
             else
                {
                    //same as above but for false
                    System.out.println("No");
                } 

        }
```

The fact is it is much easier to use conditionals with boolean values as opposed to testing 2 strings for equivalence.

Answer (score -1):

The above advices should do the job, but I would recommend you to use:

```
public String translate(boolean trueOrFalse)
{
    return String.valueOf(trueOrFalse);
}
```

because later you can easily convert that back:

```
public boolean translateBack(String translation)
{
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(translation);
}
```

but the translation string will be "true" of "false" :)

Answer (score -5):

```
String yesNo(boolean b) {
    String[] s = {"yes", "no"};
    return b ? s[0] : s[1];
}
```

EDITED with correct return

Comment: The -1 is not from me, but this it's most probably because you're needlessly creating a `String[]` in your method. You're making it harder to understand. Just simply do `return b ? "yes" : "no";`.

Comment: er, you're returning a `String` to a function that has a return type of `boolean`, not to mention the string array is *overkill*.