# How to print the result of a method with System.out.println

Tags: java

How do I print out the result of a method? I want to print out the return of translate but it displays true or false. Suggestions please.

```
/**
     * @returns the string "yes" if "true" and "no" if false
     */
    public String translate(boolean trueOrFalse)    
       {       
        if(pback == true)
            {
                return "yes";
            }
        else
            {
                return "no";
            }
        }
    /**
     * Display book info
     */
    public void displaybook()
        {
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            System.out.println("Author: " + author);
            System.out.println("ISBN: " + isbn);
            System.out.println("Pages: " + pages);
            System.out.println("Paperback: " + pback);
            System.out.println("Suggested Price: " + price);            
        }
```

Comment: Homework? Same school? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216527/how-to-write-a-method-that-translates-a-boolean-into-yes-or-no

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("Paperback: " + translate(pback));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void displaybook()
    {
        System.out.println("Paperback: " + translate(pback));       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you mistakenly concatenated your variable `pback` instead of the result of your translate method in the following statement:

```
System.out.println("Paperback: " + pback);
```

Instead, replace that statement with

```
System.out.println("Paperback: " + translate(pback));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't forget to call the method, since you wrote it for some reason, I guess.

```
System.out.println("Paperback: " + translate(pback));
```

Now, few suggestions, do yourself a favour and change the method like below. `if(pback == true)`, makes no sense. See, [The Test of Truth](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Test-of-Truth.aspx), for your amusement.

```
public String translate(boolean pback) {
   return pback ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

Well, if you don't like ternary, do this,

```
public String translate(boolean pback) {
   if(pback) return "yes";
   else return "no";
}
```

If you like braces, put braces there,

```
public String translate(boolean pback) {
   if(pback) {
      return "yes";
   } else {
      return "no";
   }
}
```

If you don't like 2 return statements, do this,

```
public String translate(boolean pback) {
   String yesNo;
   if(pback) {
      yesNo = "yes";
   } else {
      yesNo = "no";
   }
   return yesNo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public String translate(boolean trueOrFalse) {       
    if(pback == true) ...
```

Should probably be:

```
public String translate(boolean trueOrFalse) {       
    if(trueOrFalse) ...
```